# Equivalent of glDrawTexfOES in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have been using the `glDrawTexf` extension to draw labels in my Android app using OpenGL ES 1.1.

But I have now moved to OpenGL ES 2.0 and can't figure out **what is the equivalent of this call**? I could create triangles to hold the texture and draw it like a regular texture. But the `glDrawTexf` was very convenient:

- It didn't require any triangles/quads to be setup.
- You could give it screen co-ordinates.
- You could specify cropping parameters to pick smaller areas from a large texture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

However "convenient" it may have been, it was only ever that: a convenience. All it was ever doing was just drawing textured triangles.

OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't have very many convenience functions. It's a bare-bones, relatively low-level rendering API. So that means you're going to have to build those convenience features yourself.

You can easily set up an orthographic projection matrix that provides a 1:1 correspondence between vertex coordinates a pixels. This allows you to work directly in pixel coordinates. The texture coordinates of your vertex data "crop" which texels of the texture are drawn.

Comment: I feared that would be the answer. I had already started coding a shader while I was waiting for someone to respond :)